# Unable to enable Chrome app in iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-app, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to load the [native messaging example app](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/) in an external webpage as follows:

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/main.html"</iframe>
</body>    
</html>
```

I have added the `web_accessible_resources` property in the app's manifest:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  // <some code snipped>
  "web_accessible_resources": ["main.html"]
}
```

However, when I use the app within test.html, I get the following error in the console, coming from a JavaScript file within the app:

**Developer Console**

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'connectNative'
>   main.js:51

The problematic line of code is the following:

**main.js**

```
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
```

Here's a screenshot - the problem happens when I click on the Connect button (which calls the `connect` function):

[image: JavaScript Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connectNative']

Obviously, this works when the app is run standalone. How can I go about loading the app in a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. With very few exceptions, Chrome avoids proprietary extensions to the open web. You're asking for exactly that: an external web page that has nonstandard abilities simply because it's opened in Chrome rather than another browser. As the web is today, that kind of behavior would lead to a poor developer and user experience. The [native-messaging documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging) suggests that the functionality you want is available to Chrome extensions and Chrome apps. And as you're finding out, that's indeed the case: it works as an app, but not as a web-standard iframe. This is by design.

You probably want to write a Chrome extension. Your webpage should detect whether the Chrome extension is installed and whether the user's browser is Chrome. If it's not Chrome, it should give an appropriate error message. If it is Chrome but the extension is not installed, it should urge the user to install your extension.

Comment: Thanks sowbug, that's really helpful. So, I believe that the JavaScript on the page can communicate with the extension?

Comment: Yep. Look at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html. If you have more questions, please accept this answer and ask new ones in separate Stack Overflow questions.